# NSMutableDictionary losing object

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

I'm trying to store arrays of objects in an Mutable Dictionary, but it seems like the dictionary is losing some of my arrays (or maybe the arrays are losing the data?).

Anyways, here's where I'm at:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getTicketsByDay:(NSArray *)tickets {
    // take an array of tickets and return a dictionary with dates (given by
    // NSDateFormatterShortStyle) as keys and arrays of tickets as the values

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    // get NSDate object without time (only month, day, year)
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSMutableDictionary *datesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   for (Ticket *ticket in tickets) {
        NSDateComponents *ticketDateNoTimeComponents = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[ticket createdAt]];
        NSDate *ticketDateNoTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:ticketDateNoTimeComponents];
        NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:ticketDateNoTime];
        NSMutableArray *ticketArray = [datesDict objectForKey:dateString];
        NSLog(@"%lu", [ticketArray count]);
        if (ticketArray == nil) {
            NSLog(@"it's here: %@", dateString);
            ticketArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [ticketArray addObject:ticket];
        NSLog(@"%lu", [ticketArray count]);
        [datesDict setObject:ticketArray forKey:dateString];
     }
     return datesDict;
}
```

But then on the console, at random places (although the same places every time), I get something like

```
41
41
42
0
it's here: 6/29/12
1
```

even though the key for the previous objects was also "6/29/12". I've also had it print all the keys in the dictionary and there is only 1.

So somewhere I'm losing my data. What's going on?

I should also mention that I'm on 10.7.4 and using ARC.

Comment: What do you mean by "losing my data"?  The output looks like what I would expect from your code.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to use `[datesDict setObject:]` on subsequent iterations - you have already mutated the array in-place, so you are now just spinning CPU cycles.

Comment: @ConradShultz Sorry, I should have clarified. The previous objects also had a date of "6/29/12" so they should be in the same array, but it resets to 0. Then, if I print out all the keys in the dictionary at the end, there is only 1 key. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @ConradShultz Also, when I remove the [datesDict setObject:], the array never gets saved and if (ticketArray == nil) always returns true.

Comment: You can't remove it entirely, you still need it inside the `if()` to initially add it to dictionary.  You just don't need it on subsequent accesses.

Comment: Also, your method should just be named `ticketsByDay` (`get` is for methods that return by reference), but I still can't see why you are getting the results you are.

Comment: @ConradShultz Got it. Thanks for catching that weirdness. Now I'm back to where I was though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine to me (if you include suggestions from @ConradShultz)

Note that you don't need to create the ticketDateNoTime since you're using a date format, it will always generate the short format string even if the date contains a time...

So your code could be simplified to:

```
- (NSDictionary *)getTicketsByDay:(NSArray *)tickets {
    // take an array of tickets and return a dictionary with dates (given by
    // NSDateFormatterShortStyle) as keys and arrays of tickets as the values

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSMutableDictionary *datesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (Ticket *ticket in tickets) {
        NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[ticket createdAt]];
        NSMutableArray *ticketArray = [datesDict objectForKey:dateString];
        NSLog(@"%lu", [ticketArray count]);
        if (ticketArray == nil) {
           NSLog(@"it's here: %@", dateString);
            ticketArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [datesDict setObject:ticketArray forKey:dateString];
        }
        [ticketArray addObject:ticket];
        NSLog(@"%lu", [ticketArray count]);
    }
    return datesDict;
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning Objective-C so I tried your code, with 2 simple "Ticket" objects with createdAt = [NSDate date]   - I got 0; it's here: 7/07/12; 1; 1; 2

Comment: Thanks for the unnecessary code removal. The function was working fine, but I was tired and the problem I was having was in the function call, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you'll merely leak memory, and your way of replacing the dictionary entry with itself seems unusual (but I think it should work), but what makes you think you are loosing objects? You are printing the size of your array, which is different for different date strings, so maybe you just got a new date string which made it create a new array for that date?

And about the memory leaking/the unusual code: a more traditional way would be

```
NSMutableArray *ticketArray = [datesDict objectForKey:dateString];
if (ticketArray == nil) {
      ticketArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [datesDict setObject:ticketArray forKey:dateString];
      [ticketArray release];
}
[ticketArray addObject:ticket];
```

Comment: The question is tagged with automatic-reference-counting, so I would assume the OP is using ARC.  So leaks shouldn't be an issue.  I do agree with the comment on replacing the dictionary entry (see my comment above).

Comment: I did mention I was using ARC, and I've changed my code to the method you and @ConradShultz suggested.